# Passing Reference of Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I don't understand why event is passed as an argument twice.

```
changed={event => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)}
```

vs

```
click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
```

where index is only passed in once?

```
   <Person click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
         name={person.name}
         age={person.age}
         key={person.id}
         changed={event => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)}
   />
```

Comment: It's probably because the `nameChangedHandler` uses the event object. However, you didn't provide any context and we don't know what the methods do.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it uses event object. Why is it passed the way is it though and not just once in nameChangedHandler()?

Comment: `event => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)` is an arrow function. It's equivalent to `function(event) { return this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id) }`, so the first `event` is the parameter it takes, the second is where it passes it.

Comment: Thank you! Solves my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to use onClick (click) according to docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

The same goes with onChange (changed):

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Second I guess your Person component is inside a loop where index is generated for every iteration.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Having that in mind, index is just a variable which comes from outside of Person component.

On the other hand onChange (and also other events like onClick) allows you to access an event object (when that event occurs) inside your callback function but only if you pass it as an argument.

More about handling events: https://eloquentjavascript.net/15_event.html

Comment: there is `click` event in React. React DOM Element implementation differs in that it uses camelCase for all attributes and properties. But prop name in which you can assign event handler !== event type. Also you for custom components you can name props that can store event handlers whatever you want. `click` is completely valid.

Comment: Right, you can name props whatever you want. But for me it's just a misleading naming props similar to event types.